# Reshaping arrays from MNIST with Keras

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, keras, mnist

I need to reshape the MNIST dataset from (60000,28,28) to (60000,227,227). But, I don't want to use `cv2` or `PIL` libraries. Then I try to change pictures grayscale to RGB and apply ALEXNET, but firstly I should change image pixels.

Actually I've tried lots of things, even with Google Colab but unfortunately Colab doesn't support the `cv2`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.zoom()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html). The example in the docs shows more or less the same use case, just give it `zoom=(1, 227/28, 227/28)` and you can pass the whole array at once.

Comment: I've tried but I got some memory error, because when I apply it, all values in brackets are multiplied the same number. I tried this code `a=scipy.ndimage.zoom(X_train,8,order=0)`

Comment: @Bckandemir You need to use the `zoom` argument. Did you put that in?